# cakePHP Pagination View

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, paging

So I have Pagination setup for cakePHP.

The problem I get is in the views with the following

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »'); ?>
```

So what happens is the numbers show up fine and I can view the different pages. The problem is that the previous and next button don't show up. I have 3 pages that I am paging.

Please let me know if there is anything that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the CSS It's setting them as disabled?

Anyhow try

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
```

Comment: Did you check the html source that is generated? are they set to disabled or are they just not there?

Comment: Ya I treid that and it didn't work. This is weird because I have no clue why the next and previous button aren't working... When I printerd the output for $this->Paginator()->next... i got nothing... Maybe its a problem with Cake??

Comment: In the html source code, I see where the class is. But there is no text inside the tag which it's wrapped in.

Comment: It works now... this was the stupid error. '«'. That character for some reason is not liked by that function. If I replace that character with this '<<', then it ALL works. -.-''... maybe you know why?